# adding random numbers to a list in kdb+ Q programming language

Tags: kdb, q

I am trying to create an empty list that takes integer values.

I have tried
`a:($['int])`

I am trying to add 10 random numbers to the list but the only way i can do it is if i specify the number range(between 1-100) :
`a:(10?100)`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you could do:

```
q)/Init empty list of ints
q)a:`int$()
q)/Check what the list looks like
q)a
`int$()
q)/6h means that a is of type list of ints
q)type a
6h

q)/Append 10 random numbers between 0-100 to list
q)a,:10?100
q)a
12 10 1 90 73 90 43 90 84 63i
```

Comment: thanks, how can i add 10 random numbers without the range 1-100, but just any numbers?

Comment: Does terry's answer help?

Comment: @am45688 you could use `10?<list of numbers you want>`. For e.g.: `q)10?1 10 100 1000 10000` Or if you are interested in a specific range for e.g. between 50-100 (exclusive) then you could use: `q)10?51+til 49`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to specify a range you can use:

```
10?0i
```

This would generate any positive or negative integer.

Similarly,

```
10?0Wi
```

would generate any positive integer

Comment: See [Generate](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/deal/#generate)